# Invalid left-hand side assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

I am getting following error

`Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression (6:30)`
from this piece of code

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getCategories = async () = {
        const data = await axios.get('https://opentdb.com/api_category.php')
    }
    getCategories();
});
```

any help appriciated

Comment: `async () = {` -> `async () => {`

Answer (score 1):

Just write

```
useEffect(() => {
const getCategories = async () => {
    const data = await axios.get('https://opentdb.com/api_category.php')
}
getCategories();});
```